# Kitchen Riddle 2

Tags: riddle

> It lives in an apple
> And comes from the trees
> Dangerous to grapple
> And said in a sneeze
>
> Chew as it's jumbled
> With salt or with honey
> Good whole or crumbled
> But costs lots of money

What is it?

Comment: >! Shouldn't it read "ON" and apple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm gonna go with

> [Cashew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashew).

It lives in an apple

> The cashew nut actually lives under its apple, but close enough

And comes from the trees

> Yup.

Dangerous to grapple

> The shell of the nut is poisonous

And said in a sneeze

> Ka-choo!

Chew as it's jumbled

> "chew as" is an anagram of cashew

With salt or with honey
Good whole or crumbled

> These are some popular ways to enjoy cashews (hadn't heard about honey roasted cashews before now, though)

But costs lots of money

> Yeah :-/

Comment: +1.  I had the same answer but couldn't figure out all the explanations.

Comment: so quick :) nice work